# Cron job triggered - But expect echo nothing is working

Tags: shell-script, shell, cron

I have a shell script to download files from S3. I'm able to run the script manually and it's working fine, But when I schedule it from Cron it's triggered but except the `echo` command, nothing is executed.

#### Script

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
echo "starting"
y_day=$(date --date="-1 day" +%d)
y_month=$(date --date="-1 day" +%m)
y_year=$(date --date="-1 day" +%Y)

files=$( aws s3 ls  s3://bucket/log/$y_year/$y_month/$y_day/ | grep _mylog_ | awk -F ' ' '{print $4}')

for file in $files
do
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/log/$y_year/$y_month/$y_day/$file /opt/local_log/
done

## Next files
count=$( aws s3 ls  s3://bucket/testlog/$y_year/$y_month/$y_day/ | grep _testlog_ | wc -l)

if [ $count -gt 0 ]
then
files=$( aws s3 ls  s3://bucket/testlog/$y_year/$y_month/$y_day/ | grep _testlog_ | awk -F ' ' '{print $4}')

for file in $files
do
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/testlog/$y_year/$y_month/$y_day/$file /opt/localtestlog/
done
else
echo "No files for userlog"
fi
```

### Cronjob

```
10 13 * * * /opt/script/copy.sh > /tmp/copy.log
```

### log file (/tmp/copy.log)

```
starting
No files for userlog
```

`s3://bucket/testlog/$y_year/$y_month/$y_day/` No files in this location, so the the log correct.
But I first set of command, didn't download anything.

### Ubuntu syslog

```
Jun  5 19:04:01 ip-10-23-53-161 CRON[6984]: (root) CMD (/opt/script/copy.sh > /tmp/copy.log
)
Jun  5 19:04:01 ip-10-23-53-161 cron[6952]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Jun  5 19:04:01 ip-10-23-53-161 postfix/sendmail[7012]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Jun  5 19:04:01 ip-10-23-53-161 CRON[6979]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1490 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

I don't have mail server, so the last 3 lines are fine. But my question is, the complete command ran, except the echo, nothing processed their work. But this count command ran and the value is 0, so it did echo No files for userlog.

Comment: Also redirect the error stream to your log with `>logfile 2>&1`, or redirect the error log separately with `>logfile 2>errorlog`.  It's the error output that cron is likely trying to mail to you. Then investigate the error log and update your question.

Comment: where is the command aws? My guess is that cron is running as root and can't find one or more commands in the script

Comment: `aws s3 cp` is the command

Comment: thanks @Kusalananda and @user1794469
I redirect the error output to a file as Kusalananda  suggested and I found `aws command not found error` as user1794469  mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue seems to be that the `aws` command is not found.

You could solve this in one of two ways:

1. Use the full path of the command each time you invoke it in the script.
2. Modify `PATH` in the script to include the path of the directory where the command is found.

See also:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

Comment: I didn't understand this double quote? Are you referring my echo command?

Comment: @Bhuvanesh it's general good practice. It is probably not causing issues for you here, but it can cause problems generally and they can be quite hard to debug.

Comment: Im sorry, still im sure, are you saying instead of `echo "starting"` we can use `echo 'starting'`  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Bhuvanesh I just wanted to make you aware when it's proper to double quote expansions, as in `if [ "$count" -gt 0 ]` or using `"s3://bucket/testlog/$y_year/$y_month/$y_day/"`. It may not give you issues in _this_ script, but it would give you issues if a variable contains spaces or filename globbing characters.

Comment: @Bhuvanesh Compare, for example, `echo $string` with `echo "$string"` if you have `string='*'`